# Making Icecast SSL

Tags: ssl, centos, icecast

So I have just finished setting up Icecast on a Centos 7 VPS and everything is working perfectly fine, but i was needing my stream to be SSL...

However i'm not entirely sure how to do it, I looked at Icecast's website and found this page which says it can be done.

http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html

However I ain't entirely sure where i'm putting the  part as I pretty much just followed a tutorial online how to set it up so i'm not very familiar how it works, i do have a SSL certificate all set up and what not working with my site I just wanted the stream to be SSL too.

Any help would be great thanks!

```
 <!-- LIMITS -->
 <limits>
   <clients>100</clients>
   <sources>10</sources>
   <threadpool>5</threadpool>
   <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
   <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
   <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
   <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
   <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
   <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
 </limits>

 <!-- GENRIC -->
 <authentication>
   <source-password>password</source-password>
   <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
   <admin-password>password</admin-password>
 </authentication>
 <hostname>MyHost/IP</hostname>
 <listen-socket>
   <port>8000</port>
 </listen-socket>
 <fileserve>1</fileserve>

 <!-- PATHES -->
 <paths>
   <basedir>/opt/icecast/latest/share/icecast</basedir>
   <webroot>/opt/icecast/latest/share/icecast/web</webroot>
   <adminroot>/opt/icecast/latest/share/icecast/admin</adminroot>
   <logdir>/var/log/icecast</logdir>
   <pidfile>/var/run/icecast/icecast.pid</pidfile>
   <alias source="/" dest="/status.xsl"/>
 </paths>

 <!-- LOG -->
 <logging>
   <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
   <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
   <playlistlog>playlist.log</playlistlog>
   <loglevel>1</loglevel>
   <logsize>10000</logsize>
   <logarchive>1</logarchive>
 </logging>

 <!-- SECURITY -->
 <security>
   <chroot>0</chroot>
   <changeowner>
     <user>icecast</user>
     <group>icecast</group>
   </changeowner>
 </security>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have nothing referring to SSL.

Try replacing this

```
 <!-- GENRIC -->
 <authentication>
   <source-password>password</source-password>
   <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
   <admin-password>password</admin-password>
 </authentication>
 <hostname>MyHost/IP</hostname>
 <listen-socket>
   <port>8000</port>
 </listen-socket>
 <fileserve>1</fileserve>
```

With this

```
 <!-- GENRIC -->
 <authentication>
   <source-password>password</source-password>
   <admin-user>admin</admin-user>
   <admin-password>password</admin-password>
 </authentication>
<listen-socket>
    <port>8000</port>
    <bind-address>127.0.0.1</bind-address>
</listen-socket>
<listen-socket>
    <port>8443</port>
    <ssl>1</ssl>
</listen-socket>
 <fileserve>1</fileserve>
```

Comment: i tried this method and it just timed out on https://domain.net:8000 i also added <ssl>1</ssl> beneath port on what i had originally too with no luck

Comment: Don't forget to point to the file containing public **and** private key in the `paths` section! Also set log level to 4 and look at error.log to get an idea of what's going wrong. Although that said Icecast logging in case of TLS/SSL isn't the greatest.